# The emulator doesn't display new elements, just "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms"

Tags: windows, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

I'm just about to start to get into Xamarin to create a Windows Mobile App. I'm using Visual Studios 2019 and created an empty Mobile App. For the beginning I used a Youtube Tutorial to create a simple calculator (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCRxbnwORIM&t=967s). In the designer everything is displayed as I want it. Just when I try to start the emulator it doesn't show up the elements I created. It still shows the standard text "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!".

In the MainPage.xaml I basically just designed some basic elements as the Headline and Textboxes:

```
<forms:WindowsPage
x:Class="Taschenrechner.UWP.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:forms="using:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Taschenrechner.UWP"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<TextBlock x:Name="titleTextblock"  FontSize="38" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" Margin="0,12">Taschenrechner</TextBlock>

<RelativePanel RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.Below="titleTextblock">
    <TextBlock x:Name="firstNumberTextblock" Margin="0,6,12,0">Zahl 1:</TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="firstNumberTextbox" RelativePanel.RightOf="firstNumberTextblock" Width="250" Margin="0,0,0,8"></TextBox>

    <TextBlock x:Name="secondNumberTextblock" Margin="0,6,12,0" RelativePanel.Below="firstNumberTextbox">Zahl 2:</TextBlock>
    <TextBox x:Name="secondNumberTextbox" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="firstNumberTextbox" Width="250" RelativePanel.Below="firstNumberTextbox"></TextBox>

    <Button x:Name="Addition" RelativePanel.RightOf="firstNumberTextbox" Margin="12,0,0,0" Width="30">+</Button>
    <Button x:Name="Subtraktion" RelativePanel.RightOf="Addition" Margin="12,0,0,0" Width="30">-</Button>
    <Button x:Name="Multiplikation" RelativePanel.Below="Addition" RelativePanel.RightOf="secondNumberTextbox" Margin="12,6,0,0" Width="30">*</Button>
    <Button x:Name="Division" RelativePanel.Below="Addition" RelativePanel.RightOf="Multiplikation" Margin="12,6,0,0" Width="30">*</Button>

    <TextBlock x:Name="Ergebnis" RelativePanel.Below="secondNumberTextbox" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="secondNumberTextbox" Margin="52,12,0,0" FontSize="24">Ergebnis:</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock x:Name="Wert" RelativePanel.RightOf="Ergebnis" RelativePanel.Below="secondNumberTextbox" Margin="12,12,0,0" FontSize="24">0</TextBlock>

</RelativePanel>
```

[Screenshot MainPage.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYOVb.png)

[Screenshot Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIz5R.png)

I didn't change anything in the MainPage.xaml.cs so far.

Following the App.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.ApplicationModel;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

namespace Taschenrechner.UWP
{
/// <summary>
/// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
/// </summary>
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
    /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {


        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(e);

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
        }
        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
    void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
    /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
    /// of memory still intact.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
}
```

Link to the project:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/y2aihos2mht5122/AACjRODrXPARSEanjJYrPaTva?dl=0

I don't receive any error Messages or Warnings. Can you help me what I have to change so the emulator runs probably?

Comment: Hi , Could you show the total code of `MainPage.xaml` ? I will check it.

Comment: Yeah sure - Thank you!

Comment: Hi, thanks for updating ,however you post it in answer . From your code, there is no problem .It show correctly in my project .Even in preview view can see the result .https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6yA1.png You can show a screenshot like this.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. I edited the original post and uploaded the requested screenshot. The preview is also working without any problems. Just in the emulator it doesn't show the new version.

Comment: Okey, this phenomenon is strange . I also need to check another file `App.xaml.cs` .This can know when lauching app, which page as the root page to lauch.

Comment: I added it to the post as well.

Comment: Got it, it seems like no problem about this file . Having a try with cleaning project , and then rebuilding it .

Comment: I've tried it but still the emulator doesn't show the updated version. But now I receive two warnings that it cannot find the certificate file "xxx_TemporaryKey.pfx".

Comment: You can share a reproduced sample project here. I will check it in my local environment.

Comment: What do you mean with the sample project? Again the MainPage.xaml?

Comment: No, Sample project means your problem project only containing wrong part function.If not mind , you can upload it,and share link here.I will check it .

Comment: How can I upload the whole project? Sorry for so many confusion from my side.

Comment: You can use dropbox (https://www.dropbox.com/ )to upload file and share link wirh others . Better compressing file before uploading .

Comment: I will leave the office in a while. If you upload it, I will come back tomorrow to help you check.

Comment: I uploaded it - Thank you!

Comment: Got it , I have shared an answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From shared sample project, I got the reason. **Your created project is a Forms Application.**

[image]

Every time , the application launched to this **MainPage.xaml** in **Froms** ,not in **Universal Windows** .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="Taschenrechner.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

If you want to enter Universal Windows MainPage.xaml ,forms app need to use [Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers#pages) .

**However** , if only want to create a UWP app, when creating new project , you should choose as follow:

[image]

And the structure of project should be follow, then adding Xaml code in **MainPage.xaml** can be your want.

[image]